# How accurate is the new appraisal system?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I say "new", but I've been out of the loop for a little bit.

I used to use a third party app called "Pokegenie" to appraise my Pokemon. This would give me a rough guide on how good the Pokemon is based on their overall CP (and other values). Sometimes it would be a range, like 10-15, as well as a list of potential IV combinations, until I leveled them up high enough to give a specific IV.

[image: Base Pokegenie Scan]

However now the new in-game Appraisal system evaluates the IVs. The Pokegenie app now says that it can give a specific report on what the IVs actually are, based on this Appraisal.

[image: PoGo Appraisal]
[image: Pokegenie scan based on Appraisal]

So how accurate are these Appraisals? Do they give the actual IVs, or is it an average IV based on their current range?

For example, if one IV is 5-15, the average would be 10, but the actual IV might be 12, once they level up.

Comment: Ben, if I recall Pokegenie has been updated for the new appraisal system and is 100% accurate with exact IVs now.

If I can, to some of the people down-voting: why? I don't see an issue with the question and it's a genuine question, asking for clarification; but am open to figure out why.

Comment: The ranges provided by Pokegenie are the result of having insufficient information to determine the exact values, because Pokegenie reverses the calculation of composite stats like CP and HP to estimate the IVs. So the ranges are basically an artifact of the specific estimation method that Pokegenie uses. The ranges don't exist within the game itself.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The new appraisal system shows the exact IV's of your Pokemon:
each chunk represents 5 IV's. If the bar is empty, it's 0 IV, if it's full and a darker red colour, it's 15.

I don't use the Pokegenie app but I assume it's just looking at how full the bar is and telling you the exact IV as it can be a little tricky to tell at first just by eyeballing it.

For example, it's obvious when it's 10 or 15 IV's, as the bar's filled up right to the end of a chunk; but when it's 11 or 12 it might be a little hard to tell the difference at first. But after a little practice, I personally don't think an app is necessary to tell you what IV's your Pokemon has anymore.

Comment: +1 Pokegenie effectively take a look at these three bars and give the detail for each and the percentage to 100%. In order to have this precise point of view, you have to launch the scan of your screen while the in-game appraisal is open. If not, it will work as before the new appraisal system.

Comment: @Zoma Please don't edit in your own comments.

Comment: @Joachim Could you then improve my edit by removing this part? Or should I create a new edit with only the readability part?

Comment: @Zoma There is very little there to warrant an edit. But first this one needs to be reviewed by someone else, who might actually accept the edit.

Comment: @Zoma I agree with Joachim, it's not correct to edit in your own comment. That decision is up to the OP. If Mike S finds your comment useful, he is welcome to incorporate it into his answer. Alternatively, you are welcome to create a new answer to say what you'd like to say.

Comment: @RoijanEskor As the question is about appraisal system and not PokeGenie utilisation, creating a new answer would be useless, only repeating what is already said. But I understand that I shouldn't have edited it in.